# Android Generate APK

Tags: android, apk

I have a problem that is related to the apk that I generate. when it is installed in a device, sometimes it uninstalles and installes instead of upgrading. This makes the user lose the configs. I believe that this is related to the fact that the apk is generated in different machines. Could this be the reason? If so, how can I solve this problem, so the app always update without uninstalling.

PS. the application id is not beeing changed!

Comment: if you using android studio use signing config.

Comment: it asks to uninstall when apk are generated from different machine

Comment: if you use different machines you should use same gradle with version, version code, keys... And if you have API with SSH key, check that it's added

Comment: If there is an app installed from a different machine, the device asks to uninstall it.